# Best method to check user login and minimize database queries?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I let a user sign in, then check his cookies to see if they are okay to proceed; the cookie has his user ID and encrypted password. Can I check that on every page? Without using MySQL every time?

Edit: Session USED

Comment: You don't want to store the password in the cookie, encrypted or not.

Comment: You don't need to check session values with MySQL. Session values can only be set by your code. They are stored on the server and only *identified* by a cookie (the session id). There's no way the user can tamper with the session values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, obtain the username and password and validate them.
2. Verify that the username and password are present in the database.
3. Set a flag on the session if the username/password is valid.
4. Confirm that the flag is set to true on every new page.

The code goes here...

```
// start the session //
session_start();

// create one flag //
$_SESSION['logged'] = FALSE;

// username, password from form submit //
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);

// check once in database //
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_username', 'my_password', 'my_database');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_users` AS `u` WHERE `u`.`username` = ? AND `u`.`password` = ?";
$result = $con->query($sql, array($username, $password));

// if user existed return one row //
if($result->num_rows() == 1) {
    $_SESSION['logged'] = TRUE;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
} else {
    echo "invalid username or password!!";
}
```

For all other new pages check this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged']) == TRUE) {
    echo 'You are logged' . $_SESSION['username'];
} else {
    header('location:login_form.php');
}
```

Comment: You are checking only, that the session variable is set. If the variable contains FALSE, it will be accepted as logged in.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)?

Comment: Am actually using sessions , the main problem is checking the values with mysql

Answer (score 0):

You should use session. Session is quite feasiable for this. Just put the values in session then at each page just start session and check the session. If the user has the session then proceed otherwise send him to login page

Comment: Am actually using sessions , the main problem is checking the values with mysql ...

Comment: @Ronan Dejhero. My dear I think you went wrong some where. When we talk about session, in login process when we validate user we put the values in session only once. Then we just check that whether we are having session or not. We don't have to query again an again to tables.